# Django 1.11.8 - Slug - Unexpected Keyword argument

Tags: python, django, slug, django-1.11

I am new to django and I have started building my first app a couple of days ago. I first went through the MDN Tutorial and the Django Tutorial - building 2 "dummy" apps.

I am currently trying to develop a photo gallery app that will display all pictures belonging to a certain album. I am able to accomplish that using  in my urls.py and a class-based view, though, I would like to get a cleaner URL using . I would like my URL to look like mysite.com/myapp/my-album-name vs mysite.com/myapp/1

I know they are similar questions that have been asked here, I've went through most of them, read the Django doc about Single Object Mixins, Class Based Views and I am still not understanding how to get slug to work.

So far I've tried to:

1. Implement a slug field in my models and the corresponding slug
   values in my admin.py file:

**models**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter the name of your album" )
    album_creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    album_modified_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

**Views**

```
class albumPictures(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
```

**Admin**

```
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('album_name', 'album_creation_date')
    slug = prepopulated_fields = {'slug': (Album.album_name)}

admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
```

**Error Message:** `<class 'Albums.admin.AlbumAdmin'>: (admin.E030) The value of 'prepopulated_fields["slug"][0]' refers to '<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x107f234a8>', which is not an attribute of 'Albums.Album'.`

2. Implement a slug field in my models with a `prepopulated_from=album_name` or `prepopulated_fields=album_name`

**models (1)**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter the name of your album" )
    album_creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    album_modified_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(prepopulated_from=album_name)
```

**models (2)**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter the name of your album" )
    album_creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    album_modified_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(prepopulated_fields=album_name)
```

**Views**

```
class albumPictures(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
```

**Error Message:** `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepopulated_from'`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `models.SlugField()` does not support `prepopulated_from` or `prepopulated_fields`, so in your model you should use

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

instead of

```
slug = models.SlugField(prepopulated_from=album_name)
```

or

```
slug = models.SlugField(prepopulated_fields=album_name)
```

Secondly, in your `ModelAdmin` class, you should use a tuple of strings with the [`prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) option:

```
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('album_name', 'album_creation_date')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ("album_name",)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to put "album_name" in quotes. What's the difference between the above approach and slugify and what does slugify do?

Comment: `prepopulated_fields` is an admin feature which uses JavaScript to automatically fill a slug field while you enter text in another field or fields. [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) takes a string and turns it into a slug, e.g. `"Joel is a slug"` to `"joel-is-a-slug"`. You can use it outside of the admin, e.g. in the model’s `save` method.